# What happens when writing an empty string into a binary file by struct module in Python?

Tags: python

I am running into a problem. I use struct module in Python to write binary file. When I write a string with 5 characters, it will write 5 bytes into binary file. However, when I tried to write an empty string, something wired happened. Sometimes, it writes one byte into the binary file. Sometimes, it writes nothing. I want to know what happens here. Thank you!

Comment: Would you post some code? See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Nothing in the `struct` module writes to a file; it just gives you a way to pack arbitrary data into a byte stream that you can, among other things, write to a file.